# Processes in tmp folder

Tags: linux, process, tmp

I have an application that has a process on the `/tmp` folder, and the process creates another file or folder. If the original process gets ended by the application, will all the files created by it get deleted as well? Is there any way to get around this? Any other information related to this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever file to be removed, whatever processes current work directory, you need… something or someone to remove it.

So, if the original process gets the instructions to remove these files when terminating then, unless abnormal termination (crash / kill -9…) the files will be removed.

If no such provision is made, they will stand and remain in place until next reboot (since the /tmp is generally cleaned) or before if some cronjob is designed to periodically delete old and unused /tmp files.

If those files get removed but you would want to keep them, then either you have the possibility to rewrite your original process or the original process offers you command parameters enabling you to keep /tmp files or… have a process running in the background periodically copying these files in a safe place.